# ListView update cursor doesn't seem to have any effect (SimpleCursorAdapter)

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm sorry, I've tried looking at a bunch of other answers, but I can't get my particular implementation to work.

I have a `ListView` populated by an extended `SimpleCursorAdapter`.  In the `onCreate()` method I set it up this way:

```
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.duty_history_list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    masterCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WorkLog", null);
    list.setAdapter(new NotSoSimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.log_list_item, 
            masterCursor, 
            columns, 
            views, 
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER));
```

When an item is long clicked, the corresponding row is deleted from the db.  Here is my attempt to update the view.  With this code, nothing happens, I'm not sure why.  IT is called at the very end of `handleItemLongClick()`, after the db is updated.

```
public void refreshView() {
    CursorAdapter cA = (CursorAdapter) list.getAdapter();
    masterCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM WorkLog", null);
    cA.changeCursor(masterCursor);
}
```

Comment: Try `cA.notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing the cursor.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: OK, back at my computer. It's been a long time since I did an app with a database, but I see that in my app, I just created a new cursor adapter instance whenever I have a new cursor. Not the cleanest solution, because all those views are thrown out. Not sure why your method isn't working.

Comment: 1) Why you're setting FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER in the case You want to update cursor manually? 2) Are You sure that in 'NotSoSimpleCursorAdapter' there's not some caching logic?

Comment: Thanks @sandrstar, I forgot to change the FLAG, I had tried a content observer but couldn't get it to work either.  `NotSoSimpleCursorAdapter` is exactly the same as `SimpleCursorAdapter` except I modified `bindView()` to format a millisecond time to Locale specific time string, in the case of one view.

Comment: Strange, I've just checked the same code on my test project and it works just fine - list get refreshed after changeCursor() call. Does the issue have device / android version specific?

Comment: Not sure, targeting api v 18, min api 8, not using the support library for anything except fragments.  Device S GII Skyrocket with CM10 (android 4.2.2).  I changed my code to just create and add a new CursorAdapter instance, it actually refreshed the view, though it jumps to the top each update, I haven't started looking at how to stop that yet.